# How Can I count excel column name?

Tags: c#

I Want to import data from excel to sql,in this operation if a user can add one column extra,how can I check which column is newly added and at the same time in sql table also added the new column with the same column name like excel sheet...

I can Done read the excel column count-like below my coding

```
 protected void btn_upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add Path to Local system dynamically
        string path = string.Empty;

        path = Server.MapPath("~//files//") + Fup_Excel.PostedFile.FileName;

        Fup_Excel.SaveAs(path);
        //-----------------Execl Connection & Count Part-------------------------------------
        //create Oledb connection for Excel Fetch
        OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");


        OleDbCommand olcmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [sheet1$]", oconn);//create command for select excel file

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        adapter.SelectCommand = olcmd;//adap the command

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();//collection of data

        adapter.Fill(ds);//data's are filled to dataset

        string count = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count.ToString();//taking the Excel sheet column count



    }
```

Here after I done take count from sql table also
that code's are

```
 SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=C07-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=excel;User ID=sa;Password=**********");
        string asdf = null;
        SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand();
        scmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from information_schema.columns where table_name='table_1'";
        scmd.Connection = sconn;
        sconn.Open();
        SqlDataReader sr = null;
        sr = scmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sr.Read())
        {

              asdf =sr[0].ToString();

        }
```

and from here onwords i dont know how to check which column is newly added in excel?then that ssame name i want to insert column in sql table also..

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving all the columns from excel you need to check each columns in SQL Database whether that column is exists or not. If not exists then add to sql database.

Comment: Check ds.Tables[0].Columns with sr[0]